# Swapping values between two hashmaps

Tags: hashmap, rust

Edit Note: This code now compile see [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes).

---

I have two `HashMap`s and want to swap a value between them under certain conditions. If the key does not exist in the second `HashMap`, it should be inserted. I do not want to clone the value, since that is too expensive.

The (simplified) critical code that is not working is as follows:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ExpensiveStruct {
    replace: bool,
    // imagine a lot of heap data here
}

fn main() {
    let mut hm : HashMap<usize, ExpensiveStruct> = HashMap::new();
    let mut hm1 : HashMap<usize, ExpensiveStruct> = HashMap::new();

    let dummy = ExpensiveStruct { replace: false };

    hm.insert(1, ExpensiveStruct { replace: true});
    hm1.insert(1, ExpensiveStruct { replace: true});

    match hm1.get_mut(&1) {
        Some(ref mut x) =>
            match hm.entry(1) {
                Entry::Occupied(mut y) => { if y.get().replace { 
                    mem::swap(x, &mut y.get_mut()); 
                    } 
                },
                Entry::Vacant(y) => { y.insert(mem::replace(x, dummy)); }
            },
        None => {}
    }

    println!("{:?}", hm);
}
```

(On the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=205ed8f3bafabb8e3da30a0cb5a3633b&version=stable))

I get the error:

```
error[E0597]: `y` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:28:9
   |
23 |                 mem::swap(x, &mut y.get_mut());
   |                                   - borrow occurs here
...
28 |         },
   |         ^ `y` dropped here while still borrowed
29 |         None => {}
30 |     }
   |     - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I am really confused about this borrow problem and I do not see a way to fix it. If I replace the `Entry` by a `match hm.get_mut(1)`, I cannot insert in the `None` case, since the matching mutably borrows the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're giving references to references where you should be giving references.

```
&mut y.get_mut()
```

for instance is

```
&mut &mut ExpensiveStruct
```

and you're having a simular issue with

```
match hm1.get_mut(&1) {
    Some(ref mut x) =>
```

Your code works as expected when the types are trimmed down to `&mut ExpensiveStruct`:

```
match hm1.get_mut(&1) {
    Some(x) => match hm.entry(1) {
        Entry::Occupied(mut y) => if y.get().replace {
            mem::swap(x, y.get_mut());
```

([On the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e99c030f36441f5c73fa65f9b2eb0588&version=stable))

Note that the `ref mut` is removed, because `hm1.get_mut(&1)` already returns an `Option` for a mutable reference, and the `&mut` is removed because `y.get_mut()` already returns a reference.